# Google App code Submit an html form and get response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m trying to get a meeting with some local French authorities, and believe it or not, they make signing up possible on random occasions!

1. I'd like to write a macro that clicks a button every 5 about minutes that says "Effectuer une demande de rendezvous" which translated into English is "Make an appointment request".
2. Next it checks to make sure that the resulting page does not include the phrase "Il n'existe plus de plage horaire libre" which translated into English means "
   There is no longer a free time slot".
3. I need to load the page in a google apps script, tick the box, and click the button.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To make requests to the site and find out if there are slots or not you can use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#connect_to_public_apis). To compare the strings in the response message to your desired string you can make a simple comparison using `if`. But to tick the checkbox, you will will need the id or specific class attribute of the checkbox element and make a POST request to submit the form which you can also use UrlFetchApp for.